# Have development version of app installed at the same time as an installation from market?

Tags: android, mobile, google-play, development-environment

What is the best way to have a development/test version of an android app installed at the same time as the released version from market? i would like to send testers a .apk file via email they can install side by side with the currently released version available through the market. how is this possible? (it guess i could sign it with the same key so they can update the existing version, but if there is a bug in the test version they can't easily go back)

the same goes for my own device - when i want to try out the version of my app from market i always have to completely remove the development version including all my data and install it from market and set it up again.. this is pretty annoying, but i guess it's simply necessary to test my app after uploading it to the market.. and i don't have a dedicated development device..

is there a good workflow for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to change its package name. Something like: `com.you.package.test`

Comment: And an easy way to do this is to right click on the project in Eclipse > Android Tools > Rename Application Package

Comment: hmm.. the rename application package looks good.. it would be great if i could do this in an ant script or something.. but i guess renaming the package is the best way .. i'll look into that.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

FWIW there is now an easy way with android's new gradle build system.

One can simply specify a different application id for debug versions: http://www.lopez-manas.com/?p=294

```
 buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
        applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
        versionNameSuffix '-debug'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
```